# To set selected item of Spinner by value, returns -1

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-studio-2.3

i am using the following code to set selected item of a spinner by value. but the position that i get is -1.

**Code:**

```
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, location_days2);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        location_days.setAdapter(adapter1);
        String b = "5 Days"; 
        int a = adapter.getPosition(b); //this should return 5, but returns -1
        location_days.setSelection(a);
```

**String Array:**

private String[] location_days2 = {"Select days","1 Day", "2 Days", "3 Days", "0 Days", "5 Days","6 Days"};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = adapter.getPosition(b);
```

replace adapter with **adapter1** in the above line, because you have initialized adapter as "adapter1"

Comment: Yeah its working now. that's a silly one @sathiya

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to set selection in spinner

```
int pos = 0;
String[] location_days2 = {"Select days", "1 Day", "2 Days", "3 Days", "0 Days", "5 Days", "6 Days"};
for (String location : location_days2) {
   if (location.equalsIgnoreCase("5 Days")) {
       pos = Arrays.asList(location_days2).indexOf("23");
       break;
      }
    }
location_days.setSelection(pos);
```